# How to replace an internal capital letter in a string

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I have a range of strings as follows:

```
vec<-c("Peronospora boniNhenrici","Cystoseira abiesNmarina","Niplommatina rubra",
 "Padina sanctaeNcrucis","Nachygrapsus NaurusNliguricus","Melphidippa borealis")
```

I would like to replace the internal capital "N" in the second word for each element with "-", so that it would like:

```
("Peronospora boni-henrici","Cystoseira abies-marina","Niplommatina rubra",
 "Padina sanctae-crucis,"Nachygrapsus Naurus-liguricus","Melphidippa borealis")
```

Any suggestions? I've got the locations using the following:

```
stri_locate_all(vec,regex = "[N]")
```

but I'm not sure how to replace the "N" if it's internal. When I try to replace the capital letter "N" using gsub, it replaces all occurrences of N, rather than only the internal "N".

Comment: An idea to look for *non word boundaries* -> [Replace `\BN\B` with `-`](https://regex101.com/r/7fCGtq/1) (`gsub` with `perl=TRUE`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look for any N's surrounded by `\w`, which in regex matches any alphanumeric characters or underscores. If that's too broad you could replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` to only match letters:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(vec, "(\\w)N(\\w)", "\\1-\\2")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use look behind to replace `"N"` in the middle of the word with a `"-"`

```
gsub("(?<!^)\\wN", "-", vec, perl = TRUE)

#[1] "Peronospora bon-henrici"  "Cystoseira abie-marina"  "Niplommatina rubra"
#[4] "Padina sancta-crucis" "Nachygrapsus Nauru-liguricus" "Melphidippa borealis"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` with capture groups

```
gsub("([a-z])N([a-z])", "\\1-\\2", vec)
#[1] "Peronospora boni-henrici"  "Cystoseira abies-marina" "Niplommatina rubra"         
#[4] "Padina sanctae-crucis"       
#[5] "Nachygrapsus Naurus-liguricus" "Melphidippa borealis"
```